# Content in div in div, inner div width doesn't stretch

Tags: css, html

I have the following construct:

```
<div name="outerContainer" style = "background: green; overflow: auto">
    <div name = "innerContainer" style = "background: red">
        <div name = "content" style = "width: 150%; height: 20px"/></div>
    </div>
    <div name = "innerContainer" style = "background: yellow">
        <div name = "content" style = "width: 120%; height: 20px"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result is that the red and yellow divs will cover the initially visible part of their content, however, when scrolling to the right, their content overflows (implicit overflow: visible) but they retain their 100% width.
What do I need to change in order to make the red and yellow innerContainer divs cover their whole content?

The content divs are supposed to have a dynamic length and could be replaced by any other element. In this particular case, it could be solved by just giving the width of the content divs to their containers, but that wouldn't work if the content is an element without a defined width.

Comment: Why using percents higher than 100?

Comment: What exactly do you want? I mean what is the problem?

Comment: Is this what you want? [http://jsfiddle.net/HqH3W/](http://jsfiddle.net/HqH3W/)

Comment: `content divs ` , `spacer divs`....which divs are these??....atleast put a comment in the code to identify!!
Also, very unclear question....

Comment: Your markup logic is invalid, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pnp8E/1/) and divs aren't self closing tags

Comment: @Aycan Yaşıt By spacer divs I meant the divs that have a spacer characteristic, which currently are the content placeholders. I renamed them for clarification.

Comment: @P5Coder My question was what needs to be changed in order to make the red and yellow innerContainer divs cover their whole content. As stated afterwards, this must not be achieved by just using the width of the innermost divs. The inner divs are just used here to represent some random content that exceeds 100% width.

Comment: @Patsy Issa Fair enough. I actually work in an XHTML context, however, this problem applies regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

HTML:

```
<div style = "background: green; overflow: auto;">
    <div class="child" style = "background: red">
        <div style = "height: 20px"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child" style = "background: yellow">
        <div style = "height: 20px"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.child{width:120%;}
.child:first-child{width:150%;}
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/MLJVe/1/)

Comment: Maybe I should clarify, the innermost divs are just there to represent random content, replace it with <span>longlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglong</span> or whatever.